# Creating plugin in QGIS to access PostgreSQL?

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql, qgis-plugins

i want to develop a plugin in QGIS to access to my database in postgres :

i want to import a file.sql that contains my SQL Code in a textbox , and execute this code to assign myd database.

Comment: Have you created a QGIS plugin before? Or do you need help with both creating a plugin AND performing the specified functions?

Comment: I have never created a plugin in QGIS. but i learnt about creating plugin with " plugin builder" i just need help in the script . Thank u @ Radar

Comment: We can't really help you if you don't provide us with details where your script fails to execute. Also you don't need to write a plugin if you just wanna access sql in python

Answer (score 5):

You could use psycopg module for connection between python and pg

First [install psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/):

basic connection:

```
connect = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres")
cursor = connect.cursor()
query = "select * from information_schema.columns"
cursor.execute(query)
#cursor.fetchone()  #one row
results = cursor.fetchall() #all rows
for result in results:
    print result
cursor.close()
connect.close()
```

[Doc de psycopg2](http://pythonhosted.org/psycopg2/)